# multivalued attributes and foreign keys

Tags: oracle

read many posts but still confused.. So,

I want to make something like this -a single user have multiple friends. for example
 user

user_id->U1  ,   frdlist->U2,U3,U4

So, for this I have a table named user having user_id as primary key AND 
a table named frdlist having user_id and frd_ids, I am confused how to make frdlist table.
In this user_id and frds_ids column both are foreign keys referring to the same column(user_id) of the parent table(user) .

How to make this. plz help. I am using oracle 11g .

Comment: You seem to have the right idea, there's no problem having more than one column being the foreign key referring to the same primary key.

Comment: Please find the link for sqlfiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1c35).This is how your requirement works.Dont be confused about this.The first thing you must do ,to try what you want ,and if that not works ask here in `SO`.As mentioned by Neil,there is no problem with your approach ,Enjoy:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple. Your schema would be

```
user (
    user_id       PRIMARY KEY
  , first_name
  , middle_name
  , last_name
  ....
)

frduser (
    friendshipid  PRIMARY KEY
  , user_id       FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES user(user_id)
  , friend_id     FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES user(user_id)
```

A unique constraint on `(user_id, friend_id)` of `frduser` would not be sufficient as it will look for a unique combination of values, not unique values. You will need to write a DML trigger on `frduser` that would prevent any insert / update / delete of duplicate user-friend values.